# Keeping panels centerd vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two panels in VB.Net.  The parent panel `(panel1)` is docked to the form meaning it resizes when the form resizes.

The child panel `(panel2)` is supposed to be at the centre of panel1, however when its parent or the form resize, the centre is not kept by panel2.

In short how can I keep panel2 at the centre of panel1 at all times?

I use VB.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    Panel2.Top = (Panel1.Height - Panel2.Height) / 2
    Panel2.Left = (Panel1.Width - Panel2.Width) / 2
End Sub
```